# How do I lessen the amount files in my UWP app?

Tags: uwp

[image: The Error]When I try to upload my UWP app to the microsoft store, It gives me an error saying that my package contains more than 16 files. I tried lessening the amount of files by deleting some Tile Pictures and smaller logo sizes, but when i try to compile it, Visual Studio tells me it needs those files.

Is there any way to lessen the amount of files I have?

Comment: Could you please show me the detailed error message? This is not a general submission error. There is no file amount limitation for uploading packages but package size limitation. Another question is how do you package your app?

Comment: What way do you take to upload files to store? Do you mean you are going to publish an app, and upload your package?

Comment: @ Roy Li - MSFT I updated the post with the picture

Comment: Is it a complete app like Vincent asked? Or a dependency library because the name of the app seems to be dependencies?